# Java Code is opening Chrome URL through selenium However not able to Click on button

Tags: javascript, java, selenium

Below is the code i have written to open the URL in chrome browser and click on button on it. However inspite of trying to click button by xpath, by class and CSS selector it does not get click.Any suggestions what is wrong with the code?
P.S: I am new to this community and java.

```
  public void testUntitledTestCase() throws Exception 
  {
    for (int i = 1; i < 364 ; i++) 
            {
                driver.get("URL+i+");  
                driver.findElement(By.xpath("(.//*[normalize-space(text()) and normalize-space(.)='Docs'])[1]/following::div[12]")).click();
                driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@value='graphiql-container']")).click();
                driver.findElement(By.className("execute-button")).click();
                driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[contains(@class='execute-button')]")).click();
                driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@class='execute-button']")).click();
            }
  }
```

Below is an HTML part:
CSS Selector:

## graphiql-container > div.editorWrap > div.topBarWrap > div > div.execute-button-wrap > button

Xpath:
//*[@id="graphiql-container"]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]/button

Class:
"button class="execute-button" title="Execute Query (Ctrl-Enter)"

Comment: is there any exception trace ?

Comment: Update the question with the relevant HTML

Comment: Yes its showing null pointer exception with java error 64

Comment: Can you give an example url, or a sample html where it happens? Also, which line is throwing the null pointer exception? As wild guess: check if the button is in a frame. If it is, you will have to switch to that frame before interacting with the button.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try opening the URL directly without putting inside for loop. Give the complete URL and check whether you are able to click the button.

driver.get("URL");

Comment: Without Loop it opens the URL,however again at the point of clicking at the button it gives null pointer exception

Answer (score 0):

I have worked with Selenium (Java) in a project a couple of months ago and had some issues to deal with - especially with testing ajax-based websites. I ended up using Arquillian Graphene - a bunch of Selenium extensions, that add functionality and already deal with some of those issues. You should definitely have a look at it:

http://arquillian.org/arquillian-graphene/

Other than that, I can share some bookmarks that helped back in those days:

http://www.testautomationguru.com/selenium-webdriver-how-to-wait-for-expected-conditions-using-awaitility/
http://www.naveenautomationlabs.com/2018/04/mystery-of-staleelementreferenceexcepti.html